# How do I check if an item exists and modify it or return the original object

Tags: reactjs

```
export const basketReducer = (state = { total:0, items:[]}, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_ITEM":
      const item = [...state.items, action.payload]

      const updateBasket = state.items.map(el => {
        if (el._id === action.payload._id) {
          return {
            ...el,
            quantity: el.quantity + action.payload.quantity
          }
        }
        return item
      })
```

Comment: note that even though you encountered this problem in the context of React, the actually problem is just a plain JS problem, having nothing to do with React. So remember to use the correct tags to make sure folks who know how to solve your problem see your problem. Having said that: you're mapping with a variable called `el`, not `item`. Your code is fine, you just have a typo that you didn't notice. Using a good code editor that can check whether your var names exist in the scope you're using them would have caught this, so find an extension to flag these errors and never run into this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code is close.

1. First check if `state.items` array already contains *some* element with a matching `_id` property.
2. If there is a match then shallow copy the state and shallow copy the `items` array and update the matching element.
3. If there is no match then shallow copy the state and append the new data to the `items` array.

Reducer case logic:

```
case "ADD_ITEM":
  const hasItem = state.items.some(el => el._id === action.payload._id);

  if (hasItem) {
    // update item
    return {
      ...state:
      items: state.items.map(el => {
        if (el._id === action.payload._id) {
          return {
            ...el,
            quantity: el.quantity + action.payload.quantity
          }
        }
        return el; // <-- return current mapped element if no change
      }),
    };
  } else {
    // add item
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.concat(action.payload),
    };
  }
```